# Session value in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In login page,
session is added as below

```
Session["Admin"] = ddladmin.SelectedValue;
```

But how can I call it to another page in c#.net.

EDIT

Thanks for the help.But in the second page

```
   public DataSet GetDoc(string _No, bool _IsInit, CService.U _dt, string _Administrator, string _SysDocType)
      {


           string selectedAdmin = HttpContext.Current.Session["Admin"].ToString();

          try
          {
            conn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
            conn.Open();

           string _sql = "SELECT * FROM " + _tblnpf + "DOC WHERE No=@No AND USERDEP='Quality' AND Administrator = selectedAdmin";
```

when i added as above the selectedAdmin is showing error((GetDoc(): ORA-00904: "selectedAdmin": invalid identifier)).but Actually i want the the session value to be placed after "Administrator = " of below code. If I place "Administrator = "DOCTOR", it is working but when I put the session value-selectedadmin it is not "

```
        string _sql = "SELECT * FROM " + _tblnpf + "DOC WHERE No=@No AND USERDEP='Quality' AND Administrator = selectedAdmin";
```

Comment: `string selectedAdmin = Session["Admin"].ToString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the session from any other pages like the following:

```
string selectedAdmin = Session["Admin"].ToString();
```

If you are accessing from a static method the you should use like this:

```
string selectedAdmin = HttpContext.Current.Session["Admin"].ToString();
```

The issue is with the way you are passing the value to server, use its value instead or pass the value as a param like this: `Administrator = @selectedAdmin`

Comment: Thanks for the help.I want to place that session value in string _sql as above .

Comment: @shimsur: oh yes, that's possible, what's your difficulty in that?

Comment: In string _sql ,when I type Administrator = selectedAdmin,the session value is not appearing.

Comment: string selectedAdmin = HttpContext.Current.Session["Admin"].ToString();
is capturing the session value.

Comment: @shimsur: The issue is with the way you are passing the value to server, use its value instead or pass the value as a param like this: `Administrator = @selectedAdmin`

Answer (score 1):

`selectedAdmin` is a variable holding the string that you're accessing from the session conetxt.

You can't include a string variable inside another string like that because the program just thinks its text. You have to *concatenate* the strings together, which you are already doing with the `_tblnpf` variable, so do the same thing with `selectedAdmin`:

The line should read:

```
string _sql = "SELECT * FROM " + _tblnpf + "DOC WHERE No=@No AND USERDEP='Quality' AND Administrator = " + selectedAdmin;
```

Note: Composing SQL statements by adding strings together is dangerous and poses a significant security risk. You should always use SQL parameters (like what you're doing with @No) to pass in variables.

Comment: While in the `FROM` clause there isn't much choice, in the `WHERE` clause in this case using parameters is preferred, as you wrote, and I think you should have used a parameter in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this also,try this.

```
string selectedAdmin = (string)(Session["Admin"]);
```